# Accounts.createUser issue. How to make email field non-unique?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am currently working on a project that involves using **Meteor** JS.

My problem is that I can't have duplicate emails addresses (I would like username to be unique, not the email).
I keep getting error:

```
Error: Email already exists. [403]
```

According to the Meteor documentation, username is "*A unique name*", therefore I expected it to be the "constraint"...

I am creating a new user as following:

```
Accounts.createUser({
    username: "SOME_UNIQUE_STR", email: "EMAIL", password: "123", profile: profile_object
        }, 
    function(err){...
```

**My question is:** How can I force *username* to be the uniques field so I could have users with same *email* addresses?

Thank you!

Comment: Try storing the email in the profile object.

Comment: it's kind of confusing, why would you want email address to be duplicate. if email address is not of any use for your project, you can simply ignore the field and create user.

Comment: the problem is that it(Accounts.createUser) doesn't let me create user without email

Answer (score 1):

The meteor docs only guarantees uniqueness of emails in the emails field of a user.

You can build your own Authentication. One of the good tutorial you can find [here](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/roll-your-own-authentication/).